# Can I use my private key and pw to access MyEtherWallet on a new CPU? If so, how?

Tags: myetherwallet, private-key, keystore

My hard drive pretty much melted because Dell laptops suck.  I saved my private key and would like to access myetherwallet from a new computer.  When I enter the private key on its own as a "Keystore File (UTC / JSON)" it wont accept it.  I assume thats because it needs to be in a specific format.  Can I format a Notepad file so it will accept my private key?  If so, how?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can access your wallet using your private key by visiting MyEtherWallet, going to "Send Ether & Tokens", selecting "Private Key", enter in your private key and click the unlock button. After that you should be able to access your wallet again.

Comment: I tried this.  The format of the notepad file does not work.  How do I successfully enter the private the key?  I probably need a specific step by step explanation if anyone can help with that.  

Can I enter the private key by opening a notepad file that has the Private Key saved?  Or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Nevermind.  I entered it wrong haha.  What a relief!  Sorry for taking your time.